# Credited with someone else's suggested edit

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

I went to my history of suggested edits and I saw a pending suggestion. I didn't remember making it, so I went to it (https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27694848).

[image]

I was surprised when I saw this, because I was sure that I never made this edit. I think that SO might have mixed my edit up with someone else's.

One thing that might have happened is that I wrote an edit improving formatting, and I forgot about it. After a while, two edits had already been suggested to the post (there was an orange banner at the top of the screen). Then, I saw the post was closed, and there was no way to retract an edit, so I moved on. Maybe SO attributed one of the other two suggestions to me?

For now, I've changed the comment on the suggested edit to "I didn't make this edit. SO must have confused it with someone else's edit. Please reject this edit if you come across it in review."

Comment: This can happen when you edit a post while someone else edits the post as well. So the "Im a noob" part was in the original version, you started editing, someone else removed that and then you saved your edit still containing the original "Im a noob". Since it got removed in the meantime SO credited that sentence to you, since your edit contained that change in comparison to the latest version. But I wonder why you haven't removed that in your edit.

Comment: @Tom If it was there, I don't think I noticed it. I was concerned with just small formatting fixes.

Comment: I found some similar questions: [Edits happening while another Suggested Edit is in the queue](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308431), [Is there anything you can do to not seem like an idiot when edits collide?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/360272) and [Where did this text come from in my edit?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/300842)